# Multidimensional array foreach function

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, echo

I have a multidimensional array and I use `foreach()` to display it as a menu. But only the last element is displayed. Can someone explain why this is happening and how to fix it?

```
{$sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT ID, Nome, ID2 FROM tipo WHERE Tipo2 IS NULL ORDER by ID, ID2");

$result2 = $sql->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

print_r ($result2);
mysqli_free_result($sql);
 }

?>

<ul>

<?php

{reset($result2);
extract ($result2);

foreach ($result2 as $row);

echo "<li><a href=\"/{$row['Nome']}/\">{$row['Nome']}</a></li>";
} ?>
</ul>
```

Array:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array ( [ID] => 1 [Nome] => Example1 [ID2] => 1 )
    [1] => Array ( [ID] => 2 [Nome] => Example2 [ID2] => 2 )
    [2] => Array ( [ID] => 3 [Nome] => Example3 [ID2] => 3 )
)
```

Only Example3 will be displayed.

(I use different ID for other reasons, I would do a dynamic menu, but not now.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `foreach ($result2 as $row);` iterates the entire array without being told to do anything.

Then when it is done, you are echoing the last iterated row.

Simply change to:

```
foreach ($result2 as $row){
    echo "<li><a href=\"/{$row['Nome']}/\">{$row['Nome']}</a></li>";
}
```

p.s. Get rid of: `{reset($result2);` and `extract ($result2);`